# Sequelize @6.3.4 can't connect to docker -> postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, connection, sequelize.js

[image]

Nodejs:

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const fn =async ()=>{

  const sequelize = new Sequelize.Sequelize('postgres://a:a@localhost:5432/a')

  console.log('1');
  try {
    // setInterval(()=> console.log(`>>`), 1000)
    const a = await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.', a);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
  }
  console.log(`>>>ss`)
}

fn()
```

Only logs out:

```
1
Done in 2.41s.
```

Which is odd. It closes my node server, no error, just shuts down.

---

So I tried port 5432 on:

- localhost
- 192.168.0.1
- 192.168.65.0
- 0.0.0.0 (docker ps shows `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp`)

But no chance to work. How are you able to connect to the db? I always had issues with docker on windows, seems to be setup on a different network than what my browser and node.js process can access.

[image]

If I use adminer, it can access the db. (I can login and see db)
[image]

dockercompose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: a
      POSTGRES_USER: a
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: a
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Pg admin works*

Docker inspect:

```
"PortBindings": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

---

Do you guys know what to do?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show that pgAdmin can't connect. It just shows that you haven't registered any servers in pgAdmin.

Comment: how to register? Usually it shows a plus button, but none now. also node.js with correct connect string can't connect

Comment: IIRC (don't have it installed on my current machine), right click on the _Servers_ node.

Comment: Thanks, seems like it's working with postgres. Now remaind the issue with sequelize I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to run `yarn add pg pg-hstore` to work.